# How do I force Play Store to provide ONLY armeabi-v7a APKs when I download App Bundles with an arm64-v8a device?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-app-bundle

I'm currently testing deploying a separate app with a Unity Android project as a Dynamic Module. Said project only has `armeabi-v7a` and `x86` native library files.

It works just fine with `bundletool install-apks --apks <path of my built APKS file with the armeabi-v7a libs> --adb <path to adb> --modules=<Unity module name>`, generating the Unity module's `armeabi-v7a` apk just fine, but when I deployed it to the Play Store, it crashes for some reason - unfortunately, I didn't check the logcat when it happened.

I replicated that crash somewhat by copying the `armeabi-v7a` files into the `arm64-v8a` folder in the module. It was an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` pertaining to the `UnityPlayer`'s lifecycle notifier or something, and that, in this particular case, was caused by the device expecting 64-bit libs while the ones in the `arm64-v8a` folder were 32-bit.

I assumed this means the PlayStore wasn't delivering the Unity module's libs because it was an `arm64-v8a` device while the only available variants are `armeabi-v7a` and `x86`, though I could be, and am very likely to be, wrong in this.

For the record

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        ndk { abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86' }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

exists in both my base module's Gradle file and the Unity module's, and I moved the `bundle` block from the Unity module to my base module.

So what am I missing?

Comment: The `abiFilter` is the way to go if you don't want to include the 64-bits library. Play will still serve the 32-bit library to devices that support it without any configuration on your side. I know that's not helping much, but at least you know that it's not a distribution issue. We'd really need the stacktrace to understand the issue better.

Comment: Can you open the AAB file generated by Unity and tell us the directories available under the directory "base/lib"? That would give extra information as of whether the 'abiFilters' is correctly set.

Comment: I didn't refer to the AAB generated by Unity. I was referring to a Unity-exported Android Studio project that I'm trying to convert into a dynamic module for another app.

Comment: I meant, whatever AAB you upload to Play Store.

Comment: I managed to work around this problem by getting the guy who provided me with the project to build for `arm64-v8a` along with the usual targets. My problem right now is that it works just fine when I install it with the `bundletool`, but when I download it from the Play Store, apparently the native libraries got left out - the app crashed when I try to launch the `UnityPlayerActivity` because: `dlopen failed: libunity.so not found`.

Comment: @Gensoukyou1337 Did you manage to fix this? I'm stuck with the same for over a week now.